# Trac doesn't see logged with basic authentication user

Tags: trac

After upgrading server to Debian Wheezy I get a strange problem: after login via basic auth (which works), trac opens, but looks like I not logged in into it, like anonymous. And I cannot create task, comment and so on.

After upgrade system I reinstall trac via standart python ./setup.py install, and nothing else.
How to fix this?

Comment: 'Standard python' way and Debian packaging doesn't produce entirely predictable results, you know. But without a DEBUG log of the login request there's not much to say about it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont't know what the cause of the problem, but after recreation new working dir, reconfiguring apache to this new dir, all works fine.

Comment: If you had a backup-copy of the old Trac environment and Apache configuration, you could probably get an answer by comparing old and new side-by-side. If not, missed chance, and there is not much to learn from it.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I have both copies, but haven't time to do this :(